# Click icon, pop up div, and click elements except div disappear

Tags: jquery

.menuLeft is menu icon.
.mainMenu is a whole div menu pop up.
With my following code, everything works fine except when mainMenu is on, clicking .menuLeft would let .mainMenu disappear and then pop up again...

Other types of ways are more than welcome. Cheers.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.menuLeft').click(function() {
            $('.mainMenu').slideToggle('fast');

            });
            $(document).mouseup(function (e){
                var container = $('.mainMenu');

                if (!container.is(e.target)
                    && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
                {
                    container.hide('slow');
                }
            });
         });
```

HTML as following:

```
      <div class="headerMain mobile_disappear">
      <div class="container">
    <div class="menuLeft cur">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="mobilelogo">
        <?php echo '<a href="'. home_url() .'"><img src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/logo.gif" /></a>'; ?>

    </div>
    <div class="menuRight cur">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please post ur html as well

Comment: `if(!$(e.target).closest('.mainMenu').length)` will do the trick.

Comment: That works the same way. The only problem now is that clicking '.menuLeft' class would trigger the container to show up again when .mainMenu exists.